# XSLT conditional variable

Tags: variables, xslt

I have a relatively simple problem. (At least I think it's simple).

I'm pulling values from a SharePoint 2013 list. I have the following code:

```
<xsl:variable name="target">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@NewWindow = 'Yes'">
      <xsl:value-of select="_blank" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="_self" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

What I want is the following:

```
if NewWindow = Yes
  target = _blank
else
  target = _self
```

The code above just prints out Yes when I call it using {@NewWindow} or nothing at all when using {$target}.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Are _blank and _self node names or it is text you want to pass? As if it is simple text then you should use <xsl:value-of select="'_blank'" /> and <xsl:value-of select="'_self'" />.

Comment: That worked! I guess I was forgetting the inner quotes. I didn't realize I needed them. Thank you!

Comment: I voted to close, because "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value inside the `select` attribute is an XPath expression, not a static value. As an XPath expression, `_blank` would select elements with the name `_blank`.

To use a static value, you can either use `<xsl:text>`, or nothing at all.

With `<xsl:text>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="target">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@NewWindow = 'Yes'">
      <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>_self<xsl:text>
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

With just the values:

```
<xsl:variable name="target">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@NewWindow = 'Yes'">_blank</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>_self</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```